# Is it possible to invoke a method defined in Node js file from Html or plain js file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

There is one method in one nodejs file, i need to invoke that method by a button click in an HTML page. How to include the Node js files in HTML file, and how to invoke that method. I googled it alot, but can't get the exact solution, Can anyone help me to solve this problem ?

Comment: You haven't yet figured out where Node(the server) and the browser(client) diverge as it seems.

Comment: Hi Nicholas Kyriakides, I am not getting you clearly, actually, I am having the Node file and plain js file , html file in same machine and viewing via browser in the ame machine, not in remote area.

Comment: It doesn't matter - it's still a client-server architecture, in your case they are on the same location. You need to understand that concept first before doing anything else otherwise you will be lost - this is web-dev 101. Node.js is not a file you include in the browser, it's the server environment itself therefore I doubt you are on the setup you think you are.

Comment: what should i do for that . Is there any way to invoke the method defined in Node js file from the HTMl page ?(by HTTP or any method if available) . Actually i include the Plain js file into HTML file directly by '<script src="myplain.js" type="text/javascript"></script>' , but i can't achieve this to include the node js file . Please help me

Comment: You should read on web-development 101 - There is also an answer below but I highly doubt you'll be able to follow anything in it.

Comment: maybe [RPC](https://github.com/substack/dnode) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

node.js runs on your server, not in the browser.  To call something on the node.js server, you define a route on your server and you issue an Ajax call from the browser Javascript with the URL that will hit that route.

The Ajax request from the browser can then cause the previously defined route to execute on your node.js server and a result can be returned from the ajax call back to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

you are mistaking node its a server side framework not a client side html means that you are trying to execute it client end that can never be possible.

solution is

use rest service to invoke the Function

**sample Code:**

```
router.all("/rest/invoke",function(){
//write your code here 

})
```

invoke this code from html using your server name + call path

like 
    http://127.0.0.1/rest/invoke?params="123"